# "5 weeks time span" or "5 week time span"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-structure

Q1: Which one is correct?

> We executed two experiments over 5 weeks time span

OR,

> We executed two experiments over 5 week time span

Q2: is it ok to write `time span` as two words?

Q3: is it ok to write `5 weeks` or `5 week` as two words?

Comment: The answers here might be helpful: [a two hour leave VS. two hours leave](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/45977/9161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope someone comes up with a more authoritative source, but to my understanding, neither is quite correct.

You'd want to use

> We executed two experiments over **a 5-week time span**.

or

> We executed two experiments over **a time span of 5 weeks**.

or even

> We executed two experiments over **5 weeks**.

Q2: sure.

Q3: "5 weeks" is two words, "5-week" as an adjective is one word.